# xamarin.forms java.exe exited with code 2 in vs 2017

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm getting this error in my xamarin.forms project which is so annoying, 'cause I've tried all the following solutions but none of them worked!!!

- Enabled Multi-Dex
- Set max heap size to 1G (even 5G)
- Disabled sign .apk
- updated all the nuget packages(xamarin.android.support packages which is actually what caused this error in the first place!)
- I also updated JDK!!
  does anybody have any solutions rather than all the above?

**EDIT**

This is the full error:

```
10>"C:\Users\Home\Desktop\Vebko\Vebko\Vebko.Android\Vebko.Android.csproj" (Rebuild;BuiltProjectOutputGroup;BuiltProjectOutputGroupDependencies;DebugSymbolsProjectOutputGroup;DebugSymbolsProjectOutputGroupDependencies;DocumentationProjectOutputGroup;DocumentationProjectOutputGroupDependencies;SatelliteDllsProjectOutputGroup;SatelliteDllsProjectOutputGroupDependencies;SGenFilesOutputGroup;SGenFilesOutputGroupDependencies target) (1) ->
10>(_CompileToDalvikWithDx target) -> 
10>  CREATEMULTIDEXMAINDEXCLASSLIST : warning : can't write resource [META-INF/LICENSE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [commons-lang3-3.5.jar:META-INF/LICENSE.txt])
10>  CREATEMULTIDEXMAINDEXCLASSLIST : warning : can't write resource [META-INF/NOTICE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [commons-lang3-3.5.jar:META-INF/NOTICE.txt])
10>
10>
10>"C:\Users\Home\Desktop\Vebko\Vebko\Vebko.Android\Vebko.Android.csproj" (Rebuild;BuiltProjectOutputGroup;BuiltProjectOutputGroupDependencies;DebugSymbolsProjectOutputGroup;DebugSymbolsProjectOutputGroupDependencies;DocumentationProjectOutputGroup;DocumentationProjectOutputGroupDependencies;SatelliteDllsProjectOutputGroup;SatelliteDllsProjectOutputGroupDependencies;SGenFilesOutputGroup;SGenFilesOutputGroupDependencies target) (1) ->
10>(_CompileToDalvikWithDx target) -> 
10>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2610,3): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 2.
10>
10>    260 Warning(s)
10>    1 Error(s)
10>
10>Time Elapsed 00:01:23.09
========== Rebuild All: 9 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Enable MSBuild diagnostic level logging and rebuild, add the full error reported to your question.

Comment: @SushiHangover I did as you said

Comment: `....can't write resource [META-INF/LICENSE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry....` Post your proguard file (this is a common error...) OR convert to using the new D8 dexer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55818734/4984832